# In Unity, how can I change a variable from a different script when the script and gameobject is unknown?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner (very, very new to unity) working on a game where GameObjects can move from 'slot' to 'slot' in my scene. When a spell is cast, it needs to target a slot rather than a specific game object, and whatever game object is in that slot will be affected.

I've been racking my brain on how to target a 'slot' rather than a game object, and I'm at a loss. I know how to use find game objects by name and by tag, and how to access their components, but I can't find a way to access a script from within a script when I can't reference a game object's name or its script's name.

In other words:

- Enemy1HealthScript is a component of GameObject Enemy1Health, which is associated with 'Slot3' -- whatever that means.
- Enemy1HealthScript contains a public nonstatic int called 'health'.
- AllySpell1Script contains a function that needs to find and alter Enemy1HealthScript's 'health' int, **using Slot3 as its only means of identifying Enemy1HealthScript.**

My best idea was the following: at the beginning of the game, Enemy1HealthScript runs the following function:

```
 void DeclareTag()

     {
         gameObject.tag = "Slot3";
     }
```

changing the tag of its GameObject (Enemy1Health) to Slot3. I can of course change this tag at any time, from any script, at any time throughout the game--which is convenient. Then, AllySpell1Script, whenever the spell is cast, runs this function:

```
 void SpellEffect()
 {
     GameObject.FindWithTag("Slot3");
 }
```

and finds the object Enemy1Health, within which Enemy1HealthScript is located. However, after searching extensively online, I wasn't able to find a way to access the 'health' int from within Enemy1HealthScript using this idea.

What's the best solution(s) to the problem? Was I on the right track by manipulating the GameObject's tag, or is there a more efficient/simpler solution? I feel as though I'm missing something fairly simple. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

```
GameObject enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("Slot3");

if(enemy != null)
{
  enemy.GetComponent<Enemy1HealthScript>().health -= damage;
}
```

Edit: Anyhow, avoid changing variable of other script like that.
Create a new method in Enemy1HealthScript

```
void Damage(int damage)
{
  health -= damage;
}
```

then in your AllySpell1Script

```
GameObject enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("Slot3");

if(enemy != null)
{
  enemy.GetComponent<Enemy1HealthScript>().Damage(damage);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand--With the way I'm doing it now, as I explained in the question, I can't type >Enemy1HealthScript< into the Ally1SpellScript because Enemy1 might not be in slot3--it might be enemy2, or enemy4, in which case Ally1SpellScript might need to find Enemy2HealthScript, or Enemy3HealthScript, etc. Are you implying that I should have a common health script for all enemies, then use the slot tags to identify which enemy is being targeted? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: exactly yes, use just one generic script to handle the health for all your enemies